# OBD2 CAN BUS problem with data receive from AT MA

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii, elm327

im using the Bluetooth ELM327 adapter (in Amazon the Blue one) and im trying to access to steering angle on a citroen c4. My problem is that i get unexpected data, nothing to do with the ISO protocol (AT SP 6).
My elm327 configuration is this:

AT SP6

AT AL

AT L1

AT H1

AT D1

AT CRA 773 *i think this is the steering ID.

Im monitoring with AT MA but getting the next data that i really dont understand:

> A0 00 4F 3D FF FF FF 00
> 00 00 4F 3D FF FF FF 00
> 00 00 4F 3D FF FF FF 00
> FF FC FF FE 00 22 80 00
> 00 FC FF FE 00 22 80 00
> 00 FC FF FE 00 22 80 00
> 00 FC FF FE 00 22 80 00
> FF 35 00 07 BA 00 00 00
> 00 35 00 07 BA 00 00 00
> 4D 00 70 00 7F 68 00 00
> 00 00 70 00 7F 68 00 00
> 73 20 02 500 20 F0FF 35 00 000 35 00 D018 00 00 000 00F000FF 35 0000 35 00 3000 00 900 00 90FFF 35 00 0700 35 00 10000 00 A0 00 7FF00FF 35 00 8100 50 4F00 00 B000 00 B0 0FF 35 00 00000 35 040033A0 0000 00 4FF00FF 35 0000 35 00 A000 00 D01800 00 FFF 35 00 000 35 00 30000 00 E0 00 7F F00FF 35 0000 35 00 0D00 00 F000 00 F0FFF 35 00 08100 51 484000 00 00 00 00 F0000FF 35 00 35 00 01000 00 17300 20 FFF 35 00 0700 35 00 30A0 00 401800 00F00FF 35 00 00 35 00 D00 00 3000 00 30F0FF 35 00 000 35 00 6000 00 40 00 7F F000FF 35 00800 52 488000 00 500 00 50FFF 35 00 070000 35 0A300300 00 00 04 F00FF 35 00 00 35 00 F00 00 70 1800 00 0FF 35 00 000 35 00 60A0 00 4F00 00 4FF000FF 35 000 35 00 8400 00 9000 00 90FFF 35 00 08100 53 4AB00 00 A0 000 00 F000FF 35 000 35 00 F100 00 B07300 20 F0FF 35 00 00 35 00 F5018 00 00 000 00F000FF 35 0000 35 00AF00 00 D000 00 D0FFF 35 00 0700 35 00E70A0 00 4F00 00 4F00FF 35 00 800 54 46E00 00 F000 00 F0F0FF 35 00 00000 35 FD300300 00 00 04 1F00FF 35 0000 35 00C0000 00 101800 00 FF 35 00 0700 35 00EF000 00 20 00 7F 7F0FF 35 00 00 35 000100 00 00 00 00 00FFF 35 00 08100 55 00DA0 00 4F0000 00 F0000FF 35 00 35 0000800 00 507300 20 FFF 35 00 000 35 0000 18 00 00 0000 00F00FF 35 0000 35 00F9 00 00 7000 00 70F0FF 35 00 000 35 000 00 00 80 00 7F 7F000FF 35 008100 5600800 00 9000 00 90FFF 35 00 070000 35 00A03A0 00 00 00 4F00FF 35 00 00 35 004500 00 B018 00 00 0FF 35 00 000 35 0000F00 00 C0 00 7F 7F00FF 35 0000 35 000000 00 D0 00 00 D0FFF 35 00 08100 57 00300 00 E0 000 00 F00FF 35 0000 35 006E 00 00 F07300 20 F0FF 35 00 00 35 0000FA0 00 4F18 00 00F000F00 400000 00 F000FF 303 61 8AF 00 D00 00 D00018 00 FFF 35 041 00 E0 00 7F00 00 E000 00 E0F00FF 35AF 00 F0 00 7F00 00 F000000 00F0FF 35 81 51 43C 00 000 00 00000000 0F0000FF 13 00 10 00 7F00 00 100007300 FFF 35 03C 00 20 00 7F A0 00 4018 000 0F0FF 3566 00 30 00 7F 00 00 300000 00 FFF 35 D6 00 40 00 7F 00 00 40000 00 4F000FF 81 52 4838 00 500 00 50003000 0FFF 35 00 35 0017 00 600 00 6000 00 60F00FF 303 61 8FF9 00 700 00 700018 00 F0FF 35 EF 00 80 00 7FA0 00 400000 00 F000FF 301 00 00 07 DC00 00 000000 00 FFF 35 081 53 42E 00 AO

I will like some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your adapter, `ATMA` (monitor all) may or may not respect the filter set via `CRA`. What happens when you use `ATMT733` (monitor transmitter)?